# Recursive function won't return array from another function; Am I missing something?

Tags: php, arrays, tail-recursion

Consider the following: I am using gzipped .cvs reports downloaded through an API to render data live (constructTable). First I check to see if the file has been downloaded, then if it's complete (more thorough check should be implemented, just don't know how yet). If everything's okay, it should read the file and turn it into an array - which I return to the recursive function which in turn returns it to my constructTable function. But the array won't return from the checkReport function to the constructTable. What am I doing wrong?

```
function fileToArray($filePath){
  $file = fopen($filePath,'rb');
  $gzipcsv = fread($file, filesize($filePath));
  fclose($file);
  $ungzipcsv = gzdecode($gzipcsv);
  return parse_csv($ungzipcsv);
}

function checkReport($filePath,$queryStr,$status=''){
if($status!='ok'){
  if(!file_exists($filePath)){
    if($status!='creating_report'){
      DownloadReport($_SESSION['currentUser'],$filePath,$queryStr);
      $status='creating_report';
    } else {
      usleep(100000);
      $status='downloading_report';
    }
  } else {
    if(filesize($filePath)!=0){
      $fs = filesize($filePath);
      usleep(100000);
      clearstatcache(TRUE, $filePath);
      if($fs==filesize($filePath)){
        $status='ok';
      } else {
        $status='downloading_report';
      }
    } else {
      $status='zero_filesize';
    }
  }
  checkReport($filePath,$queryStr,$status);
  } else {
  return fileToArray($filePath);
  }
}

function constructTable($user, $fields, $dataType, $reportName, $conditionItem, $conditionId, $dateRange) {
$filePath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/csv/'.$GLOBALS['customer'].'__'.$dataType.'__'.$reportName.'.csv.gz';

  $queryStr = 'SELECT '.implode(',',$fields);
  $queryStr .= ' FROM '.$reportName;
$queryStr .= '';
if($conditionId!='') $queryStr .= ' WHERE '.$conditionItem.' = '.$conditionId;
    $queryStr .= ' DURING '.$dateRange;

$csv_array = NULL;
$i = 0;
while(!$csv_array){
 if($i++>2){
  break;
  }
  $csv_array = checkReport($filePath,$queryStr);
  var_dump(checkReport($filePath,$queryStr));
}
```

Comment: Just looking at the code briefly, you could try doing 'return checkReport' when calling recursively

Comment: @eclipse31 O ffs. Cheers.